# Horizontally Center h1 Next to an Image

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and I have the logo in the top left of the screen. The title for the page should be centered on the page but because of the image, it is being pushed to the right. The code I have in CSS and in HTML is:

```css
#logo {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="logo" src="logo.png">
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
</body>
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: What's your "*[mcve]*" HTML that accompanies this CSS?

Comment: I added the html that I have into the main body of the question

Comment: What is their common parent element?

Comment: They are both in the <body> section, I forgot to add that into the code when I added the HTML

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}

.header__img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <img
        class="header__img"
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567446537708-ac4aa75c9c28?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80"
        alt=""
      />
      <h1 class="header__title">Home Page</h1>
    </header>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how your solved it, and why that solves it.